# AsyncTask Error on doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Can someone help me figure out why AsyncTask occasionally crashes?

Heres my Code:

```
 public class statuspage extends MapActivity {

LocationManager locationManager;
MapView mapView;
Criteria criteria;
Location location;
Geocoder gc;
Address address;

String bestProvider;
String LOCATION_SERVICE = "location";
String addressString = "No address found";
StringBuilder sb;

private MapController mapController;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statuspage);

    // Get Mapping Controllers etc //
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(17);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Add the MyLocationOverlay //
    myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocation);
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();

    // Animates the map to GPS Position //
    myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mapController.animateTo(myLocation.getMyLocation());
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    // Executes GeoCoding AsyncTask //
    new GeoCoder().execute();

    // Location Manager Intiation
    locationManager = (LocationManager) statuspage.this
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    criteria = new Criteria();

    // More accurate, GPS fix.
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // More accurate, GPS fix.
    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {

        // Latitude and Longitude TextView
        TextView etlongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlongitude);
        TextView etlatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlatitude);

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Latitude and Longitude TextView Display Coordinates //
        etlongitude.setText((longitude) + "");
        etlatitude.setText((latitude) + "");

        // locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) location);
        locationManager = null;

    }

    return false;
}

class GeoCoder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("Class == GeoCoder", "AsyncTask == doInBackGround");

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        gc = new Geocoder(statuspage.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {

            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude,
                    longitude, 1);

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                address = addresses.get(0);

                int noOfMaxAddressLine = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                if (noOfMaxAddressLine > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    addressString = sb.toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            addressString = e.toString();
        }
        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        TextView scrollview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        scrollview.setText("Your location:" + "\n"
                + "(Accurate to 500 meters)" + "\n" + (addressString));

        Log.d("Class == GeoCoder", "AsyncTask == onPostExecute");
        return;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    new GeoCoder();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    new GeoCoder().cancel(true);
    myLocation.disableMyLocation();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    new GeoCoder().cancel(true);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new GeoCoder().cancel(true);

    // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    // Vibrate Service
    vib.vibrate(50);

    startActivity(new Intent(statuspage.this, AgentPortalActivity.class));
    statuspage.this.finish();

    /** Fading Transition Effect */
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

    return;

}
 }
```

Heres my Logs:

```
 04-20 09:23:15.449: D/Class == GeoCoder(22493): AsyncTask == onPostExecute
 04-20 09:23:16.082: D/Dialog(22493): dialog button was clicked
 04-20 09:23:16.136: W/MapActivity(22493): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@40685938
 04-20 09:23:16.140: V/MapActivity(22493): Recycling map object.
 04-20 09:23:16.167: I/Maps.MyLocationOverlay(22493): Request updates from gps
 04-20 09:23:16.167: I/Maps.MyLocationOverlay(22493): Request updates from network
 04-20 09:23:16.179: I/Maps.MyLocationOverlay(22493): Request updates from gps
 04-20 09:23:16.183: I/Maps.MyLocationOverlay(22493): Request updates from network
 04-20 09:23:16.238: I/MapActivity(22493): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
 04-20 09:23:16.238: E/MapActivity(22493): Couldn't get connection factory client
 04-20 09:23:16.281: D/Class == GeoCoder(22493): AsyncTask == doInBackGround
 04-20 09:23:16.300: W/dalvikvm(22493): threadid=28: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #16
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at com.jetdelivery.mobile.statuspage$GeoCoder.doInBackground(statuspage.java:111)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at com.jetdelivery.mobile.statuspage$GeoCoder.doInBackground(statuspage.java:1)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
 04-20 09:23:16.390: E/AndroidRuntime(22493):   ... 4 more
```

Heres Line 111:
     double latitude = location.getLatitude();

I've been trying to figure it out for days, tried searching on here, on google, followed some examples, no luck.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I can't see any point in your code where you initialise `location` before executing your `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start the GeoCoder task before initializing the location object in isRouteDisplayed(). You should start it after getting the location and testing for null, that means after line:

```
if (location != null) {
```

You could also test it for null pointer in doInBackground but without it the whole method looks useless.

The crash happens just sometimes because you do not know when the task will be started. That means sometimes the thread which created the GeoCoder task will keep running, initialize the location object than the task takes control. However, this happens just sometimes. In other cases the task starts before the first thread reaches the initialization code for location and crashes.

Comment: I cant believe that was the problem... Starting the location after if (location != null) did the trick! I cant thank you enough.